# How do I uninstall a java applet?

Tags: java, internet-explorer-7, java-applet

In IE, how do I go back and revoke a java applet from running after I have allowed it? Its not in Add/Remove Programs. Is there anyway to see a list of installed/allowed applets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Control Panel and open Java icon.
Under the Security tab click Certificates... button.

Select Trusted Certificates from the dropdown. Under the User tab select the entry corresponding to the signer of the applet in question.
Use Remove button to stop trusting java signed by that certificate.

Close out the open dialog boxes.
Your browser should go back to asking for permission for the applet in question.